# synchronization database RESTful API

Tags: java, sql, rest, synchronization

My aim is to built a trusted synchronization between both local DB and server DB with NO conflictions or deadlock.
I suppose that a user may request his transaction using DML (insert, update and delete) from his local DB  where there is NO access to the Interent and when he wants he asks for *sync* and send all the transaction with the data i need to the server via RESTful API.
My problem when tow *sync* operations has performed in a different time and different user which may cause a conflict (ex. the first user update a row and the second user tries to update the same row but another column while they were both offline before sync operations).
In the local DB i track every transaction on another table for every type of transaction (inserted_table , updated_table and deleted_table) every one of them contain table_id,row_id and time.
My question when i send these information to the server for the first user when he asks for sync and then after while the second user makes sync too how i can know the information for the first sync process for the first user(like time of the transaction in the local for the first user) to make rollback if i need and how to mange the conflict resolution?

Answer (score 0):

The whole synchronization logic is up to you to decide how it should work!

One solution to your problem is to add columns STATUS(varchar) and LASTMODIFICATION(datetime). When syncing the databases, you can choose the most recent by comparing the LASTMODIFICATION field and overwrite the data with the newest update.

Comment: thank you for your comment . it's not my problem , my problem is how to mange the conflict resolution.